# Change View color after drag

Tags: android

I want change background of a view after drag a view and before drop.i am using dragShadow builder but can not access view object after drag.

if any one know this then please tell me.

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start drag, you can pass the `View` which is being dragged to the `localstate` of the drag and drop framework.

```
v.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, v, 0);
```

Here, v is a Button in my case, which is being dragged. Note, i have passed `v` in the third parameter, which represent `localstate`.

Now when Drag event occur, you can get the `localstate` instance.

```
case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
    Button button = (Button) event.getLocalState();
    break;
```

Now, you can perform any valid action to the button when ACTION_DROP event will occur.
Similarly you can do this at any `DRAGGING EVENT`.

See [AddToCart](https://drive.google.com/?tab=wo&authuser=0#folders/0B0-ZGUib2PXXTWlMcFpUS2RWNEk) for full source code.

See [Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NSR9OB4CSuw)  link